# Why am I not able to use a number in php public function class at starting?

Tags: php

So I'm trying to create a page, and the software I use, uses the below code to create pages:

```
public function 2testnew()
    {
        $pagetitle = "testnew";
        $this->SetVars(compact('pagetitle'));               
        return $this->render(dirname(__DIR__) . "/" . self::_VIEWS_PATH . "/" . self::_PAGES_DIR, __FUNCTION__, TEMPLATE_NAME);
    }
```

Unfortunately, when I start my page name with "2" at the beginning of the page name, my website stops working, and also on Notepad++, it shows "2" in orange color, meaning there's something wrong.

I'm a beginner at PHP, so please guide me. How do I achieve a class starting with a number instead because I want to create a page that has a number at the beginning of the name?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Explain what software are you using and url what you trying to reach, as well as what product are you using right now(php framework or CMS).

Comment: I use PHP framework.

Comment: What framework? and post url what you type in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something incomplete in your [error reporting settings](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting). When properly configured you'd get something like:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '2' (T_LNUMBER)

Why doesn't PHP parser expect a `2` character there? Because it isn't a valid class method name. It's admittedly not documented where you'd expect it to but it can be found in the [functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) chapter (class methods follow the same rules as regular functions):

> Function names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. **A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore**, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: `^[a-zA-Z_\x80-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x80-\xff]*$`.

If you absolutely need to, how can you? You can hack it with e.g. [magic methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call):

```
class MyController
{
    private function twotestnew($one, $two)
    {
        echo 'Calling ', __METHOD__, '() with arguments ', $one, ' and ', $two, "\n";
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $map = [
            '2testnew' => 'twotestnew',
        ];
        $name = mb_strtolower($name);
        if (isset($map[$name])) {
            return call_user_func_array([$this, $map[$name]], $arguments);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException('Not found');
    }
}
```

This could use many refinements but I hope you get the idea. You can test the above code with the [variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) syntax (for good or bad, the syntax doesn't apply to function definitions):

```
$page = new MyController();
$page->{'2testnew'}('Foo', 'Bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your function name is invalid. Function names in php cannot start with a number. You can read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

Comment: Then what do I do if I want to create a function name that starts with a number? :(

Comment: @Nore, You can't. As with any other syntax violation - there's nothing much you can do about it. Can you please accept the answer for future askers?